# Python deepcopy.. kind of

Tags: python, reference

Is it posible to only deep copy a certain types of object, such as a list, a dict, or a tuple

Example: `[[1, <SomeObj>], <OtherObj>]`

I want to deep copy the first list (and of course.. the 1), but not `SomeObj` or `OtherObj`. Those should stay as refereces.

Is that possible to do that with some function that i'm not familiar with or do i have to write my own function?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no utility to do that. The built-ins `copy` and `deepcopy` require that objects provide their own `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` methods to override the default behavior. Which is not a good idea IMHO, since you don't **always** want the same kind of copies...

Writing a function to do that shouldn't be hard, though. Here's an example that works for lists, tuples and dicts:

```
def mycopy(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [mycopy(i) for i in obj]
    if isinstance(obj, tuple):
        return tuple(mycopy(i) for i in obj)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return dict(mycopy(i) for i in obj.iteritems())
    return obj
```

Comment: For larger things, this would be made more efficient by removing the `[` and `]` in the tuple branch and the `[` and `]` and changing `.items()` to `.iteritems()` in the dict branch. These alterations are also Pythonic in style.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan answer updated. Thanks for the tips, I didn't know these forms.

Comment: If you're not familiar with them, take a look at (a) generator expressions (that's what you get when you take out the `[` and `]`, otherwise it's a list comprehension) and (b) iterators (`dict.items()` produces a list, `dict.iteritems()` produces an iterator; refer to the `dict` docs for more info).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `copy.deepcopy` pretty easily by overriding the `__deepcopy__` method in each of the classes you need it in. If you want different copying behavior depending on the situation, you can just set the `__deepcopy__` function at runtime and then reset it:

```
import copy
class OtherObject(object):
    pass

l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], OtherObject()]
# first, save the old deepcopy if there is one
old_deepcopy = None
if hasattr(OtherObject, __deepcopy__):
    old_deepcopy = OtherObject.__deepcopy__

# do a shallow copy instead of deepcopy
OtherObject.__deepcopy__ = lambda self, memo: self
l2 = copy.deepcopy(l)
# and now you can replace the original behavior
if old_deepcopy is not None:
    OtherObject.__deepcopy__ = old_deepcopy
else:
    del OtherObject.__deepcopy__

>>> l[0] is l2[0]
False
>>> l[1] is l2[1]
False
>>> l[2] is l2[2]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any python tool that will deepcopy only basic types and keep other elements as references.

I think you should be able to write a small recursive function for that (under 20 lines).